# AnimationTimer stop() method does not stop

Tags: java, animation

I understood that it is possible to stop an ongoing animation from within its overridden `handle()` method using the `this.stop` function. The code below is from a game and it should stop running the animation after the game has been won and the alert has been shown. Instead the alert is popping countless times.

```
new AnimationTimer() {
  @Override
  public void handle(long now) {
    if (game.isInProgress()) {
      nextFrame();
    } else {
      if (game.isWon()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Game Over!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Congratulations, you have won the game!");
        alert.setContentText(toolbarModule + ": " + game.getLevel().getScoreObject().getScore()
            + ", Time Remaining: " + toolbarModule.getTimeString() + "\n Rank: "
            + toolbarModule.getRankString());
        alert.show();
      } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Game Over!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Sadly, you have lost the game!");
        alert.setContentText("Time passed: " + game.getLevel().getTimeLimit());
        alert.show();
      }
      new EndScene(game, stage);
      this.stop();
    }
  }
}.start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I figuered it out. Actually logical (often is). The `alert.show` function waits for the user to acknowledge the pop-up. In the meanwhile the `handle()` method runs the method multiple times. What I needed was to run this pop-up once. I did this by encompassing the alert with a condition. Like this:

```
      if (!victoryMessageReceived) {
        victoryMessageReceived = true;
        if (game.isWon()) {
          Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
          alert.setTitle("Game Over!");
          alert.setHeaderText("Congratulations, you have won the game!");
          alert.setContentText(toolbarModule + ": "
              + game.getLevel().getScoreObject().getScore() + ", Time Remaining: "
              + toolbarModule.getTimeString() + "\n Rank: " + toolbarModule.getRankString());
          alert.show();
        } else {
          Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
          alert.setTitle("Game Over!");
          alert.setHeaderText("Sadly, you have lost the game!");
          alert.setContentText("Time passed: " + game.getLevel().getTimeLimit());
          alert.show();
        }        
      }
```

Thank you everyone for the effort!